# How to group by in sql with condition

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to find users that have a count of purchase_id>x (10 in this example's case). How to condition the group by? what I did in the exam[ple below doesn't work

```
count(purchases.id), user_id from purchases
group by if(count(purchases.id)>10)
```

This is what did work (need to add a condition here)

```
select count(purchases.id), user_id from purchases
group by user_id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `having` clause:

```
select count(*), user_id
from purchases
group by user_id 
having count(*) > 10;
```

Comment: And how will I count the number users that are included in this condition?

Comment: @Z.storch . . . Make this a subquery:  `select count(*) from (<subquery>) x`.